# lower_bound in class array of struct nodes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, struct

I am trying to add a `Node<K,V> (struct)` into an array (Class) and sort it using `lower_bound`. 
When debugging my code, I realized it stopped working on:

```
auto itr = std::lower_bound...
```

This is my `add` function code:

```
    template<typename K, typename V>
bool MapSet<K,V>::add(Node<K,V> n){
  if(find_key(n.first) != nullptr){
    return false;
  }


  if(last_ == capacity_){
    grow();
  }
    else{
  Node<K,V> res;
  res.first = n.first;
  res.second = n.second;
  Node<K,V>* newarr = new Node<K,V>[capacity_];
  auto itr = std::lower_bound(ary_,ary_+last_,res);
  size_t itrind = std::distance(ary_, find_key((*itr).first));
  size_t newcount = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < itrind; i++) {
    newarr[i] = ary_[i];
    newcount++;
  }
  newarr[newcount] = res;

  for (size_t i = newcount+1; i < capacity_; i++) {
    newarr[i] = ary_[i];
  }


  delete [] ary_;
  ary_ = newarr;
  last_++;
  return true;
}
}
```

and this is the `find_key` function code:

```
   template<typename K, typename V>
Node<K,V>* MapSet<K,V>::find_key(K key){
  std::cout << "find func" << '\n';
  for(size_t i=0; i < capacity_; i++){
    if((ary_[i]).first == key){
      Node<K,V>* lol = &ary_[i];
      return lol;
    }
    else{
      continue;
    }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

and `grow()` doubles the size of the array. `Node<K,V>` has members `first(K)` and `second(V)`, and the class `MapSet` has the array `ary_` which is an array of Node,

`last_ (size_t)` is the last element of the array that is not empty and `capacity_ (size_t)` is the size of the array.

So is there something wrong with my `lower_bound` function or could the error be somewhere else? any advice? Thanks!

Edit:
I am also getting a segmentation fault at:

```
Node<K,V>* lol = &ary_[i];
```

Edit:
I fixed the errors pointed out about the sizeof(ary_) and the delete [] ary_, but I am still getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: In programming you will find that determining where the program stops working very close to the start of your investigation. Most of your time will be spent figuring out why the program stopped there.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one major problem:

```
ary_ = newarr;
delete [] newarr;
```

First you make `ary_` point to the same memory as `newarr` is pointing. You now have two pointers pointing ***to the same memory***.

Then you free the memory that both pointers are pointing to.

If you attempt to dereference `ary_` after that you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Another problem is this:

```
new Node<K,V>[sizeof(ary_)];
```

Since `ary_` is a pointer (I *assume* since you don't show us a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) then `sizeof(ary_)` gives you the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

You can easily solve both problems by stop using pointers and your own manual memory management, and instead use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I am not allowed to use vectors, lists, sort, find, and those functions for this project. would using ary_.capacity_ be better for this case?

Comment: @malaria And `std::distance` and `std::lower_bound` are allowed? weird :-/

Comment: I have to use std::lower_bound and std::distance is encouraged to use

Comment: @malaria If `ary_` is a pointer, it doesn't have a capacity or member variables. All a pointer is doing is pointing to a memory location, that's it. If you're not allowed to use `std::vector` (school assignment limitation?) then you have to keep track of the amount of memory allocated yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this using of the new operator

```
Node<K,V>* newarr = new Node<K,V>[sizeof(ary_)];
```

is wrong. The expression `sizeof(ary_)` is equal to the size of pointer that is usually either to 4 or 8 bytes depending on the used system.

The same problem exists relative to the condition in the for statement

```
for(size_t i = newcount + 1; i < sizeof(ary_); i++)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

These statements

```
    ary_ = newarr;
    delete[] newarr;
```

have a logical error.

I think you mean

```
delete [] ary_;
ary_ = newarr;
```

Also it is unclear why the initial value of `newcount` is set to 1 instead of 0.

```
    size_t newcount = 1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < itrind; i++)
    {
        newarr[i] = ary_[i];
        newcount++;
    }
    newarr[newcount] = res;
```

This call

```
size_t itrind = std::distance(ary_, find_key((*itr).first));
```

can invoke undefined behavior.

And it is totally unclear what the function `grow` does. This makes the code confusing.

Comment: newcount is set to 1 because it is going to be the next element after the first part of the array is added, then add the rest of the array. The grow() function doubles the size of the array (capacity_*2).

Comment: @malaria The first part can be empty.

Comment: I am using lower_bound to add the Nodes to the Array in a sorted manner, that is why I have to add the first part of the array then add the new element at the index of the pointer of lowerbound then add the rest of the array

Comment: @malaria As I said the first part can be empty.